# Avoid validation on click of specific button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

This question is regarding validation. I have regex validation on some fields as show in the snapshot. I want to run this validation only when user clicks on Add button; NOT when the submit button is clicked. Could someone suggest how this be done?

For some reasons, image is not visible. It's uploaded at following location:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXnUd.png

[image: To add a row:]

Answer (score 0):

Set the `CausesValidation="false"` for the submit button.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation.aspx

You could also place the RegExValidator and the Add button into a separate ValidationGroup.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, I don't want to disable all of the validations on Submit click. There are some other validations which need to be run on it's click.

Comment: you can use the ValidationGroup

Answer (score 0):

use the `CausesValidation` Property. Set to False